Inverses of Morphisms Necessarily Being Morphisms
I'd just like to ask something simple:
Does category theory (or anything else?) explain how there are categories in which the inverses of morphisms are automatically morphisms but how there are other categories where this isn't the case?
To be a bit more clear: In the category Set, the inverse of a function is always a function, in the category of groups Grp, the inverse of a homomorphism is always a homomorphism, in the category Vect$_F$, the inverse of a linear map is a always a linear map, but in the category Top, the inverse of a continuous function isn't necessarily continuous. I'm sure there are other categories you can pull examples from.
But why is this? Is something "general" lurking in the background of all this?

It's part of the definition.  $f$ is invertible if there is a morphism $g$ such that $f\circ g =1$ and....  Your topological example is flawed since a continuous function without a continuous inverse is NOT invertible in the category $\mathbf{Top}$.

In other words, you have the forgetful functor $U: \mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$, and you are asking:  if $U(f)$ is invertible why isn't $f$ invertible?

It is not clear to me how a theory could explain that some general claim is true in some cases and false in others. That would to me seem the default state of affairs. (And yes, you should have said inverse maps of maps that define morphisms, as a morphism is only invertible as a morphism if it is an isomorphism.)

@MarcvanLeeuwen Explaining is different from proving. Obviously you can't prove something that is sometimes false. However you can provide an explanation and give insight to when you should expect it to be true.

@Trebor Yes, I think one could ask what state of affairs explains the ubiquity of categories have this property, even if not all do. I think the given answers take up that challenge, and do so admirably. Yet is is not really category theory that explains why this situation exists, just like one cannot expect group theory to explain why Abelian groups are so often encountered. In the end one ends up having adjectives for various conditions that are "often" but not always satisfied, and showing implications among these adjectives.

Inverses of morphisms are morphisms by definition. What you're asking is a little different, though: you're asking when, in a category whose objects are sets with additional structure, the set-theoretic inverse of a morphism is necessarily also a morphism (in the sense of preserving the additional structure).
The right way to set up this question is to make explicit the use of the forgetful functor. So we have a concrete category $C$, meaning it is equipped with a faithful functor $U : C \to \text{Set}$, the underlying set functor. The question is:

When is it the case that if $f : c \to d$ is a morphism such that $U(f)$ is invertible in $\text{Set}$, then $f$ is invertible in $C$?

If a functor $U$ has this property it is said to reflect isomorphisms or to be conservative. As you've observed, this holds for groups and vector spaces (in fact it holds more generally for any algebraic category), but fails for topological spaces.
It's not hard to show that a faithful functor $U$ reflects monomorphisms and epimorphisms, meaning that if $U(f)$ is invertible then $f$ is both a monomorphism and an epimorphism. So the issue here has to do with the fact that, contrary to what you might expect, a morphism can be both a monomorphism and an epimorphism without being an isomorphism. These are called "bimorphisms" but I really don't like this term because it sounds like it has something to do with bicategories; I prefer the term "fake isomorphism." In $\text{Top}$ these are the continuous bijections.
Fortunately, there are many strengthenings of the concept of monomorphisms and epimorphisms, such as effective monomorphisms and epimorphisms, and you can show that if a morphism is either a mono + (effective, etc.) epi or, dually, a (effective, etc.) mono + epi, then it's an isomorphism. So, a sufficient condition for $U$ to be conservative is if $C$ has the property that either

every monomorphism is effective, etc. or
every epimorphism is effective, etc.

In an abelian category, for example, both of these are true, more or less by definition. Neither is true in $\text{Top}$; the effective monomorphisms are the embeddings $X \hookrightarrow Y$ (so $X$ must have the subspace topology) while the effective epimorphisms are the quotient maps $X \twoheadrightarrow Y$ (so $Y$ must have the quotient topology).
Maybe surprisingly, it's possible for neither of these to be true in an algebraic category; for example neither of these is true for rings. So this isn't quite a complete explanation of what's going on. We have to dig a little deeper into monadicity or something like that.

I hadn’t ever realized that monos of rings are also awful, even though it falls out of the fact that epis are, thanks for pointing that out!

I think monos in algebraic categories are nice enough, even if they aren't necessarily regular etc. For one thing, they constitute the right class of an orthogonal factorisation system!

Another sufficient condition is that, if $|A| = |B|$ and the identity is a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$, then the identity is also a homomorphism from $B$ to $A$.

Awesome answer. I would only suggest to expand the last sentence (in fact, I was about to write an answer about monadic functors). Like... Lemma. Monadic functors are conservative" (and come back to the examples with groups etc.). But if you prefer I can also flesh this out in a separate answer.

@Martin: if you'd like to flesh that out as a separate answer that'd be great. I confess I don't understand this material well enough to explain it confidently.

In mathematical logic, given a language $\mathcal L$ with constant symbols, relation symbols, and function symbols, we can define $\mathcal L$-structures and homomorphisms of $\mathcal L$-structures. Is the resulting category always an algebraic category?

@Joe: if you only allow constant and function symbols, and also potentially impose a bunch of equational axioms, then yes. I haven't thought about what happens with relation symbols.

@Joe No, the category of posets is not algebraic.

@MartinBrandenburg: Ah, I suppose that should have been obvious, since a bijective order-preserving map is not necessarily an order isomorphism. (@Qiaochu: thanks, I guess that gives us a large class of examples of algebraic categories.)

Just a small addition to Qiaochu's great answer.
Many of the examples of conservative functors (that is, functors that reflect isomorphisms) appearing in mathematical practice are actually monadic, and in fact we have the following:
Lemma. Let $U : C \to D$ be a monadic functor. Then $U$ is conservative.
This explains why the usual forgetful functors from groups, pointed sets, Lie algebras, rings, lattices, ... to the category of sets are all conservative. Also the category of compact Hausdorff spaces is monadic over sets, which (conceptually) explains why bijective continuous maps between these are already homeomorphisms.
But it also shows for example that the forgetful functor from topological groups to topological spaces is conservative. We are not restricted to the category of sets here.
Good news is that, if you have written down the proof that, for example, a bijective ring homomorphism is a ring isomorphism (invertible ring homomorphism), literally the same proof works for all the other examples. In the general setting of monadic functors it's even very simple (it has to be, this is what abstractions are made for).
Here is the proof. It is enough to prove that the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Alg}(T) \to C$ is conservative, where $T$ is a monad on $C$. Let $h : (X,a) \to (Y,b)$ be a morphism of $T$-algebras, meaning $h: X \to Y$ satisfies $b \circ T(h) = h \circ a$. Assume that $h : X \to Y$ is an isomorphism in $C$. Then $h^{-1}$ is also a morphism of algebras $h^{-1} : (Y,b) \to (X,a)$ since
$$a \circ T(h^{-1}) = h^{-1} \circ b \circ T(h) \circ  T(h^{-1}) = h^{-1} \circ b$$
And it's clearly inverse to $h$ as well. $\checkmark$
Notice that we haven't really used the monad structure at all. The same proof works for algebras of an endofunctor. And this also eliminates the need to prove the monadicty in the first place, which can be harder than proving just conservativity. For example, the category of groups embeds fully faithfully into the category of algebras for the endofunctor $X \mapsto 1+X+X^2$, hence the forgetful functor is conservative. (Here I also use that fully faithful functors are conservative
)
The forgetful functor $U$ from topological spaces to sets is not conversative, for a very basic reason: there are many continuous maps $f: X \to Y$ whose underlying map $U(f)$ is equal to the identity (which requires $U(X) = U(Y)$), and $f$ doesn't have to be the identity or an isomorphism. In fact, a set $S$ can acquire different topologies $O \subseteq O'$, and then there is a morphism $(S,O') \to (S,O)$, $s \mapsto s$, and it's only an isomorphism if $O = O'$. The same argument shows that the forgetful functor from posets to sets is  not conservative. I would say the main reason here is that you can define two structures on the same set that are strictly contained in another.
This cannot happen for algebraic structures. Say if you have two groups with the same underlying set with multiplications $m,m'$ such that $m(x,y)=z \implies m'(x,y) = z$ always holds (the graph of $m$ is contained in the graph of $m'$), we already have $m=m'$.
